# IE操作中に実行されたメッセージボックス(ポップアップ)の操作方法

Tags: powershell

PowerShellでIEを操作し自動化スクリプトを作成しています。
例えばIEを起動、指定ページにアクセスしログイン、その他必要な処理などは実現出来ました。

しかし、問題がありその必要な処理の中に「保存ボタン」を押下する処理があるのですが、
それを行うと「保存を行いますか？」とメッセージボックスが出現し、「OK」を押下しないと次の処理が動かない仕組みになっています。
これをなんとかして自動で「OK」を選択するようにしたいのですが、どうすれば良いのでしょうか。

ComObjectで下記の用に情報を取得しています。

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

これを利用してIEを指定する事はできているのですが、
メッセージボックスの情報は取得出来ていないようです。

■試行内容
最初はIDがわかればgetElementByIDで指定しようと思ったのですが、
上記の通り根本的な情報が取得出来ないので不可。
また、座標クリックを行おうと思いましたがPowerShellの方法がいまいち不明で断念。
仮に上記2つが出来たとしても、メッセージボックスが表示されている状態では、
実行中と判断され(busy = True)次のコマンドが実行されません。自分の知識ではお手上げです。

指定のサイト自身に手を加える事は出来ません。
また、UWSCなどフリーソフトを使用することも出来ません。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。